# Simplest way to add in a syntax rule

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I would like to add in the following rule to my syntax to help with python files:

```
:syn match pythonBoolean "\<self\ze\."
:hi pythonBoolean cterm=bold
```

It works when I type it in directly to the file:

[image]

However, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to have this as a default setting -- I've tried putting it in my `vimrc`, in an `after` folder, in a `syntax` file, etc. etc. but each time I get some error or other and it never ends up actually working properly.

What would be the simplest way to add the above two lines so that it will mark-up my python file with those changes (like it does when I enter it in directly)?

Comment: Did you try in a `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim` file? That should work. You mentioned trying `after` and `syntax` but not sure if exactly this path... If this path doesn't work, what do you get instead when you query syntax and highlight?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`:

```
syn match pythonSelf "\<self\.\@="
hi pythonSelf cterm=bold
```

I used a slightly different syntax group so you could customize it more; you could also `hi link` it to another group if you wanted.

Comment: I also avoid \zs and \ze in syntax matches because they make it difficult to apply syntax highlights to the characters « outside » of those matches.